# Defining types based on parent object and propagate & merge this to child object (like with Android's layout attributes)

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

In Typescript, I am trying to define types based on parent-child relationship between two objects.

What I'm after is to have something similar to Android's xml attributes. In that framework, all the layout attributes of ViewGroup are passed on to and are merged with its children Views.

I need something similar in typescript and I am wondering if it is possible to apply the parent's type to all children's attributes without having to specify the parent type for each child.
That is, I wish that I could do something like:

```
interface AttrsOfA {
   a: boolean;
}
interface AttrsOfB {
   b: boolean;
}
function a(childProvider: <AttrsfromParent>() => unknown) {
  return {
    attrs: childProvider<AttrsOfA>(),
  };
}
function b<AttrsfromParent>(attrs: AttrsOfB & AttrsfromParent) {
  return attrs;
}
```

and that it would type check the a & b properties when invoking:

```
a(<AttrsfromParent>() => b<AttrsfromParent>({
    a: true,
    b: true,
  })
);
```

Any advice on how this problem could be solved would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This does not seem right to me. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Can you clarify with concrete XML examples of what Android does?